# actionbar and wrong button pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

hello i have an actionBar with this menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_open"
    android:title=".."
    android:icon="@drawable/open_holo_light"
    yourapp:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
        android:title=".."
        android:icon="@drawable/delete_holo_light"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always|withText" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_detail"
        android:title=".."
        android:icon="@drawable/info_holo_light"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

this is when i insert my menu:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
}
```

here i press my menu items:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_delete:
        Toast.makeText(this, "delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_open:
        Toast.makeText(this, "open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_detail
        Toast.makeText(this, "detail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;            
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the problem is easy! if i press menu_open i have no toast, if i press menu_delete i have open toast, if i press menu_detail i have delete toast.. why? thanks!

Comment: Why do you use a custom scheme for the showAsAction attribute?

Comment: @Egor: because he's using the `ActionBarActivity` from compat package

Comment: How do you know on what you've pressed since all your labels are `".."`? Put a label on each item and double check then

Comment: Try cleaning your project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

And change every `yourapp:showAsAction` with `android:showAsAction`.

Comment: where i get app name from strings?

Comment: What happens if you change every `yourapp` by your app name? The app name is `@string/app_name` which is also the name that you can see in the launcher.